# Failed to parse XML drawable file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

My xml file is as below..
ADT asks me that 
"Failed to parse file E:\Applications\Vishal\Workspace\MyApp\res\drawable\day.xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_focused="false"   
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/dayoff"/>       

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_focused="true"    
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/dayon"/>

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_focused="true"    
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/dayon"/>    

     <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/dayon"/>             
     </selector>
```

here dayoff and dayon are two png images under drawable folder..

Where's Im wrong ? suggest plz.

Comment: check this example http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton

Comment: I think U need to put this day.xml in your res/menu/ folder.

Comment: @PadmaKumar Tht doesn't work..

Comment: @Ajay Tnx.. n tried.. still failed :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/dayon"/>

<item 
    android:state_focused="true"    
    android:drawable="@drawable/dayon"/>    

 <item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/dayoff"/>           
 </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is 100% right.. I think the PNG you are using may be corrupt...

OR

Check if there is any space before starting of the day.xml file.....

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 Check if any space is there before start tag of xml ....